# Issue with Parallel foreach processing

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

This is a console app and I have a foreach that iterates through a list of Id's and fetches the data for that Id from the mapper(database). Once data is fetched for every list it creates the csv file.
There are almost 84 lists each with 1000 ID's. I splitted it as I was getting out of memory exception.

```
 List<TruckSpec> ts = null;
 Parallel.ForEach(lists, list =>
        {
             string csv = string.Empty;
            long max = list.Max();
            long min = list.Min();
            ts = tsmapper.SelectByList(min, max);
            GetCSV(delimeter, ts, nameofile, filepath, mqftcall);     
        });
```

So, I decided to use parallel processing in order to speed up the process.

But, the problem is the mapper function selectByList (min, max) values change for every list. I am getting this error "Collection was modified: enumeration may not execute " when running through the mapper function.

Can you please help me here? Should I not use parallel.foreach this case ? If I can use parallel.froeach how do I fix this issue.

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception? Which collection is it talking about? Also, is `tsmapper.SelectByList()` thread-safe? If not, you can't use it like this.

Comment: If you call .ToList or .ToArray on the list, you are working with a copy of the original-list. maybe this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that when using multi-processing you can have context switches at any time. You could hit line 7 (ts = tsmapper.SelectByList(min, max);), then before hitting line 8 hit line 7 3 more times. Finally, once you hit line 8 with the first thread the data could have changed significantly.

Or GetCSV could be busy iterating through ts when a context switch happens, changing the data.

Based on your usage it looks like List ts = null; should just be declared inside the parallel loop, rather than outside of it.